# How to recover SQL Server corrupted database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, data-recovery

I have application implemented which having the SQL Server 2008 database at back end. Suddenly it showing in suspected mode. Unfortunately I do not have any backup. I need to recover this database. What I need to do?

Comment: Look at [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/10/sql-server-2005-restore-database-using-corrupt-datafiles-mdf-and-ldf-part-2/) or [this article](http://www.sqlserverclub.com/articles/how-to-recover-from-a-corrupted-sql-server-database.aspx). You may get some help.

Comment: Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, adding `suspected` and `mode` does not mean you're talking about "suspected mode".

Comment: Don't worry man... not worth. it does mean sql database under suspected mode.

Comment: For Closers...Don't you think sql Script is programming ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Script worked for me. I got this from [here](http://lalitcdhake.blogspot.in/) . Perfect working

Comment: +1 for answering your own question