# mdf file is corrupted now how can i recover my ms sql server 2008 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My database .mdf file got corrupted and I have no means to get my schema s.I tried  with a few soft wares available on the internet but its turns out that all of them being demo versions don't give back the repaired file.Is there any other means by which I can restore my db?
I am using MS SQL 2008

Comment: You need either a backup or a fat bank account.

Comment: This question's comments have information about the very same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242017/how-to-recover-sql-server-corrupted-database

Comment: @MarcelloRomani i have detach database so now this is not working

Comment: This user http://lalitcdhake.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-recover-suspected-database-in.html says he moved the mdf and log files to another server machine and attached them to the sql server instance running on that machine, plus he run a script that "fixed" the db. Hope this helps...

Comment: using [SQL database recovery software](http://www.sqlrecoverytool.com/) for recovering corrupt SQL database from mdf file is a helpful and time saving technique.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Go ahead and delete your .ldf file.

Then Execute the below scripts.There are three.So choose one according to your condition.

-- Method 1

```
 USE [master]
    GO
    -- Method 1: I use this method
    EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='TestDb',
    @physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQ\DATA\TestDb.mdf'
GO
```

-- Method 2:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

Method 2: If one or more log files are missing, they are recreated again.

There is one more method which I am demonstrating here but I have not used myself before. According to Book Online, it will work only if there is one log file that is missing. If there are more than one log files involved, all of them are required to undergo the same procedure.

-- Method 3:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Source:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/26/sql-server-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file-in-database/

Comment: Pretty much any answer beginning "Go ahead and delete your .ldf file" without any kind of caveats of disclaimer is worth a downvote. Also I don't see how trying to reattach the mdf without the ldf will help at all as it is the mdf file that is corrupted.

Comment: i deleted ldf file.. method 1 is working for me thanx rajan

Comment: If the mdf is corrupted, the accepted answer cant work... it needs repair.